# why am i getting an Invalid Hook call in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here's my code that is giving the `Invalid Hook Call` error and I am not able to figure out what exactly i did wrong. How do i achieve what i am doing in this code without calling the hook within the functions ?

```
const useTimer = ({ days  =0 , hours = 0 , minutes = 0 , seconds = 10 , millis = 0  } :{days?:number , hours? : number , minutes ?:number , seconds? : number , millis? : number} )=>{

  const [time, setTime] = useState({ days , hours , minutes , seconds , millis });
  const [started , setStarted] = useState(false) ; 
  const originalTime = { days , hours , minutes , seconds , millis }


  const countDown = ()=>{
    setTime(t=>{
      let totalMillis  = 1000*(t.days * 24 * 3600 + t.hours * 3600 + t.minutes * 60 + t.seconds ) + t.millis ; 
      return {
        days : totalMillis/(24*3600*1000) , 
        hours : totalMillis/(3600*1000) , 
        minutes : totalMillis/(60*1000) , 
        seconds : totalMillis/1000 , 
        millis : totalMillis%1000
      }
    })  
  }

  const onTimeout = (callback : Function)=>{
    callback() ; 
  }

  const reset = ()=>{
    setTime({...originalTime}) ;
  }

  const stop = ()=>{
    setStarted(false) ; 
  }

  const start= ()=>{
    if(!started) setStarted(true) ; 
    setInterval(()=>{
      if(started) countDown() ; 
    } , 1 ) ; 
  }

  return {time , start , stop , reset , onTimeout} ; 

};
```

Here's the full error Message :

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

The error happens in the 2nd line itself : `const [time, setTime] = useState({ days , hours , minutes , seconds , millis });`

I am using this hook like this :

```
const App = ()=> {

    const { time } = useTimer({ days: 10 });
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{time}</h1>
      </div>
    )

}
```

To make this library I am using : `create-react-library` package. Here's the link to my repository : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/use-timer-react

Comment: What's full message of the error ?

Comment: There are multiple problems, no idea which one is causing `Invalid Hook Call` if you don't show how you call this hook and which line does the error point to. The biggest problem is conceptual though, I recommend reading [Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) and [React state with calculated fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931596/react-state-with-calculated-fields) BEFORE attempting to fix this code

Comment: i have updated with the error and the way i am using now

Comment: can't call time directly because you declare time is object with property

Comment: You can only use `useTimer` in a Function component, which `App` is not.

Comment: I made the App as Function component but still same issue

Comment: I am not able to use 'useState' at all within useTimer.

Comment: You have patterned `useTimer` as a custom hook, but really you just want an ordinary function. Ditch `useState` and just use `let` for `time` and `started`.

Comment: Hooks are code that React calls on the update cycle. I don;t think you need hooks in this use-case.

Comment: @Nateshbhat the answer has been already posted. Read the react rules (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) . You have only two option. Either you convert `useTimer` as pure react component by returning a render function or make it pure js function by removing hook calls(`useState`, `setState`).

Comment: That said, here's an example [`useTimer`](https://github.com/thibaultboursier/use-timer/blob/master/src/useTimer.ts) hook that may be usedful.

Comment: @The_ehT - misleading, hooks do not render.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I never said hooks do render. I said make `useTimer` pure react component by returning render function somewhat like this https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-cache-63pf9

Comment: @The_ehT, I do not think that is a custom hook. It defeats the purpose, and I do not see any counting happening.

Comment: @Nateshbhat, I just tried your code, you are pretty much there - just reference `start` and call it before render (and use timer.minutes). The original error message is gone now that you have App as a function component.

Answer (score 1):

There were some bugs in your code so I made some fixes. Below is the working version. Please let me know if you need any explanation.

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;
function App() {
  const { time, start, stop, reset, onTimeout } = useTimer({
    days: 10,
    interval: 100,
  });
  start();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(time, undefined, 2)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const useTimer = ({
  days = 0,
  hours = 0,
  minutes = 0,
  seconds = 10,
  millis = 0,
  interval = 1000,
}) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState({
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds,
    millis,
  });
  const started = useRef(false);
  const originalTime = {
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds,
    millis,
  };

  const countDown = () => {
    setTime(t => {
      let totalMillis =
        1000 *
          (t.days * 24 * 3600 +
            t.hours * 3600 +
            t.minutes * 60 +
            t.seconds) +
        t.millis -
        interval;
      return {
        days: Math.floor(totalMillis / 86400000),
        hours: Math.floor(
          (totalMillis % 86400000) / 3600000
        ),
        minutes: Math.floor(
          (totalMillis % 3600000) / 60000
        ),
        seconds: Math.floor((totalMillis % 60000) / 1000),
        millis: totalMillis % 1000,
      };
    });
  };

  const onTimeout = callback => {
    callback();
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setTime({ ...originalTime });
  };

  const stop = () => {
    start.current = false;
  };

  const start = () => {
    if (!started.current) {
      started.current = true;
      setInterval(() => {
        if (started.current) countDown();
      }, interval);
    }
  };

  return { time, start, stop, reset, onTimeout };
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I copy pasted your exact code but I'm still getting the same error . I have no idea what's causing it :( seriously stuck . Here's my repository link for this : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/use-timer-react

Comment: @Nateshbhat Hooks are introduces in [16.8](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) but you have older versions in your package.json. I updated react-scripts as well since you are using an anciant one. You can clone [this repo](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/use-timer-react) and see if it works for you. Pull request is [here](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/use-timer-react/pull/1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:  You're calling a react hook within a nested function, this is against the [rule of react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

I can see you're trying to setstate using the usestate hooks within other functions in the react function. You might want to rethink your logic